# How to merge two dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame `D1` like:

[image]

DataFrame `D2` like:

[image]

I want to merge them like:

[image]

I used `pd.concat`, get this(This is not what I want):

[image]

How can I append C,D..... to every row in a Pandas DataFrame D1.

Comment: With the merge function build into pandas ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have only one row in the second dataframe, you can do:

```py
for col in df2:
   df1[col] = np.tile(df2[col].values, len(df1))
```

Note that `tile` just repeats the array elements up to a certain length (here `len(df1)`). This is equivalent to

```
df2[col].values.tolist() * len(df1)
```

If you need something more performant and clean, have a look at [pandas' `merge` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).